# Run route level middleware conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've spent quite a bit of time looking to see if there is anything available that will run blocks of route level middleware conditionally.

Ideally the solution would require no changes to the middlewares, and they could just be passed in as an array.

I have just implemented a very crude solution but wanted to see what people think, what issues I'm likely to face and whether there is just a better solution to this.

An example of the problem I am trying to solve is middleware1 altered something on the request that meant middleware2, 3 & 4 do not need to run.

Here's my crude solution:

```
function conditional({ condition, field, value }, middleware) {
  const conditions = {
    eq: (_this, _that) => {
      return _this === _that;
    },
  };
  return (req, res, originalNext) => {
    if (!conditions[condition](_.get(req, field), value)) {
      return originalNext();
    }
    let i = 0;
    function next() {
      if (i === middleware.length) {
        return originalNext();
      }
      if (typeof middleware[i] === 'function') {
        i += 1;
        middleware[i - 1](req, res, next);
      }
    }
    next();
  };
}

app.get(
  '/test-conditional/:condition',
  middleware1,
  conditional({ condition: 'eq', field: 'params.condition', value: 'run' }, [
    middleware2,
    middleware3,
    middleware4,
  ]),
  middleware5,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
  }
);
```

Any feedback or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve using this conditional middleware?

Comment: @Bart An example would be that something happens in middleware1 that means that middleware2-4 would no longer need to run. If there's a simple way to do this without having to modify middleware2-4 then that would be great. I have reusable middleware that runs in multiple apps that I would like to run conditionally on some routes based on session data.

Comment: Why did you choose to use multiple middleware instead of just creating one middleware that branches the logic. Your current solution seems a bit over-engineered

Comment: The multiple middlewares are a mixture of internal utility middlewares used across multiple routes and applications and external middleware libraries. The reason I'm posting this is to see if there is a nice way to do this that is not over-engineered. I guess it's hard to understand the use case without seeing the full application code.

Comment: Yes indeed. Is it possible to post a visualization?